# Request.data from post man

Tags: python

**I have JSON:**

```
{
    "ComName":"Toàn Á Châu" ,
    "ComAddress":"10 đường số 8",
    "ComPhone":"01693157366",
    "memberships":[
        {
            "User":"1",
            "Datetime":"2020-05-22T04:14:46.974+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

**I want request "User" to check with the data to see if it already exists.**

**My command:**

```
checkuser = Membership.objects.filter(User=request.data["User"]).first()
```

**Problem:**
Could not receive "User" because "User" is in:

```
"memberships":[
            {
                "User":"1",
                "Datetime":"2020-05-22T04:14:46.974+00:00"
            }
        ]
```

**I think I need to add something before "User".( request.data[....["User"])**

**Sorry for this foolishness, please help me**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I got your question correctly, you can get the user data with the following statement.

```
request.data['membership'][0]['User']
```

As you can see, `'User'` is part of the `'membership'`, so you have to access it through `'membership'`

**P.S.** I haven't check the validity of other parts of your code, but this should help you in terms of accessing JSON data

Comment: Thanks but it says the next error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: should be `request.data['membership'][0]['User']`, no?

Comment: @ExplodingGayFish yes, I just realized I didn't see the list there

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer**:

```
request.data['membership'][0]['User']
```